# Import of large CSV via PHP CLI to Foreign importer causes memory_limit Problems

Tags: php, performance, csv, import, command-line-interface

I have a problem importing a large CSV file with 400.000 rows into a database. These final import is done by an foreign import script which does some magic in a black box and i cannot influence it. This script is causing the memory_limit problems, but as i said, i have to use it. My problem is now to run the whole import. What i`ve tried is the following:

```
loop with while over original csv
read 1000 rows from csv
create a new file with these rows
give this new csv to doImport() function of the importer
```

but the foreign script still causes the `memory_limit` problems. Here is some pseude code

```
$csvLib = new foo();
$foreignImporter = new bar();

while ($thausendRows) {

    $tmpFile = $csvClass->writeCSV($thausendRows);
    $foreignImporter->doImport($tmpFile);

}
```

In sheer desperation I also tried to instanciate the csvLib and foreignImporter inside the loop to null and unset them after the loop, but that didn´t change nothing.

Any Ideas how to run the doImport in small chunks so that it don´t breaks? I increased the memory limit up to 2G on my local machine and it got the first 100.000 rows importet. But that is no option at all.

Comment: Buffer it and import it in chunks

Comment: What do you mean by "buffer it". I split it already up in 1000 row chunks?

Comment: Please tell me you know what a buffer is.

Comment: I´m not a native english speaker so I might understand you wrong. What comes in my mind when you say "buffer" are the ob_xy functions, but i don´t get what they can help me with my problem?

Comment: looks to me like the foreignImporter is not freeing up memory properly

Comment: That is the problem. But i can´t change the foreign code for some reason. So that is why i asked for some tipps to solve the probleme on my side of the code :)

Comment: i fh the problem is with code you cant change, how can you you do anything about it ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution for my Problem. The memory leaking foreign part is outsourced into an own script. My part of the script reads the CSV. Now I loop over the rows and every 1000 rows i write a tmp CSV and call the foreign part in its own script with this tmpCSV. Instead of $foreignImporter->doImport($tmpFile); I do passthrough('script.php'). Thats all. Easy...if you know :)